# GWTP, PresenterWidget and Google Visualisation API won't display PieChart

Tags: charts, widget, uibinder, gwt-platform, pie-chart

I'm new at GWT-P, but there is very little material on this topic. I'm trying to make simple pie chart widget, for testing purpose. I've made Widget presenter, view, and UiBinder.

```
    package com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client;
    import com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.PresenterWidget;
    import com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.View;
    import com.google.inject.Inject;
    import com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus;
    import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLPanel;

    public class PieChartPresenter extends
    PresenterWidget<PieChartPresenter.MyView> {


public interface MyView extends View {
    public HTMLPanel getChartPanel();

    public void drawPieChart();
}

@Inject
public PieChartPresenter(final EventBus eventBus, final MyView view) {
    super(eventBus, view);
}

@Override
protected void onBind() {
    super.onBind();


}
/*Ovde prmeniti method*/
@Override
protected void onReset() {
    super.onReset();

    /*MyView v = getView();
    v.drawPieChart();*/

    getView().drawPieChart();
}

    }
```

Then View.

```
    package com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client;

    import com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.ViewImpl;
    import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
    import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiConstructor;
    import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiField;
    import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLPanel;
    import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;
    import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.AbstractDataTable;
    import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.AbstractDataTable.ColumnType;
    import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.DataTable;
    import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart.Options;
    import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart.PieChart;
    import com.google.inject.Inject;

    public class PieChartView extends ViewImpl implements PieChartPresenter.MyView {

private final Widget widget;
@UiField HTMLPanel chartPanel;
@UiField (provided=true) PieChart pieChart;

public interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, PieChartView> {
}

@Inject
public @UiConstructor PieChartView(final Binder binder) {
    widget = binder.createAndBindUi(this);
    pieChart = new PieChart(createTable(), createOptions());
    chartPanel.add(pieChart);
}

@Override
public Widget asWidget() {
    return widget;
}
public HTMLPanel getChartPanel(){
    return chartPanel;
}

@Override
public void drawPieChart() {
    // OVAJ POKUSAJ
    pieChart.draw(createTable(),createOptions());

}

private Options createOptions() {
    Options options = Options.create();
    options.setWidth(400);
    options.setHeight(240);
    options.setTitle("My Daily Activities");
    return options;
}

private AbstractDataTable createTable() {
    DataTable data = DataTable.create();
    data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Task");
    data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Hours per Day");
    data.addRows(2);
    data.setValue(0, 0, "Work");
    data.setValue(0, 1, 14);
    data.setValue(1, 0, "Sleep");
    data.setValue(1, 1, 10);
    return data;
}
    }
```

And last UiBinder

```
        <!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">

        <ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
     xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
     ui:generateFormat='com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.format.PropertiesFormat'
     ui:generateKeys='com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.keygen.MD5KeyGenerator'
     ui:generateLocales='default'
         xmlns:c="urn:import:com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart" xmlns:v="urn:import:com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations">

     <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="chartPanel">
    <c:PieChart ui:field="pieChart" ></c:PieChart>
     </g:HTMLPanel>
         </ui:UiBinder>
```

When I load this code I get Error:
              [ERROR] [gametestingyou] - Unable to load module entry point class com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.GameTestingYou (see associated exception for details) and Umbrella exception.

Help please :) !

This is full Exception:

19:14:34.890 [ERROR] [gametestingyou] Unable to load module entry point class com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.GameTestingYou (see associated exception for details)
com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImpl.fireEvent(HistoryImpl.java:75)
    at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.fire(ValueChangeEvent.java:43)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImpl.fireHistoryChangedImpl(HistoryImpl.java:82)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.History.fireCurrentHistoryState(History.java:121)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceManagerImpl.revealCurrentPlace(PlaceManagerImpl.java:310)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.GameTestingYou.onModuleLoad(GameTestingYou.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus.castFireEventFromSource(EventBus.java:77)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEventFromSource(SimpleEventBus.java:67)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceManagerImpl.fireEvent(PlaceManagerImpl.java:146)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceManagerImpl.doRevealPlace(PlaceManagerImpl.java:121)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceManagerImpl.revealPlace(PlaceManagerImpl.java:339)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.place.ClientPlaceManager.revealDefaultPlace(ClientPlaceManager.java:24)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceManagerImpl.onValueChange(PlaceManagerImpl.java:264)
    at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.dispatch(ValueChangeEvent.java:128)
    at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.dispatch(ValueChangeEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImpl.fireEvent(HistoryImpl.java:75)
    at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.fire(ValueChangeEvent.java:43)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImpl.fireHistoryChangedImpl(HistoryImpl.java:82)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.History.fireCurrentHistoryState(History.java:121)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceManagerImpl.revealCurrentPlace(PlaceManagerImpl.java:310)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.GameTestingYou.onModuleLoad(GameTestingYou.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLPanel.addAndReplaceElement(HTMLPanel.java:197)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.PieChartView_BinderImpl.createAndBindUi(PieChartView_BinderImpl.java:33)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.PieChartView_BinderImpl.createAndBindUi(PieChartView_BinderImpl.java:1)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.PieChartView.(PieChartView.java:27)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.com$rs$gwtp$gametestingyou$client$PieChartView_PieChartView_methodInjection(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:555)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.create_Key$type$com$rs$gwtp$gametestingyou$client$PieChartView$_annotation$$none$$(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:559)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.get_Key$type$com$rs$gwtp$gametestingyou$client$PieChartView$_annotation$$none$$(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:570)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.create_Key$type$com$rs$gwtp$gametestingyou$client$PieChartPresenter$MyView$_annotation$$none$$(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:1726)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.get_Key$type$com$rs$gwtp$gametestingyou$client$PieChartPresenter$MyView$_annotation$$none$$(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:1735)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.create_Key$type$com$rs$gwtp$gametestingyou$client$PieChartPresenter$_annotation$$none$$(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:1522)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.get_Key$type$com$rs$gwtp$gametestingyou$client$PieChartPresenter$_annotation$$none$$(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:1533)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.memberInject_Key$type$com$rs$gwtp$gametestingyou$client$ShowTestResultsPresenter$_annotation$$none$$(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:2069)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.create_Key$type$com$rs$gwtp$gametestingyou$client$ShowTestResultsPresenter$_annotation$$none$$(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:2079)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.get_Key$type$com$rs$gwtp$gametestingyou$client$ShowTestResultsPresenter$_annotation$$none$$(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:2092)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.memberInject_Key$type$com$rs$gwtp$gametestingyou$client$HomePagePresenter$_annotation$$none$$(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:1341)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.create_Key$type$com$rs$gwtp$gametestingyou$client$HomePagePresenter$_annotation$$none$$(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:1352)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.get_Key$type$com$rs$gwtp$gametestingyou$client$HomePagePresenter$_annotation$$none$$(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:1365)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.access$4(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:1363)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl$5$1.onSuccess(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:1413)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.runAsync(GWT.java:255)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl$5.get(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:1411)
    at com.gwtplatform.common.client.CodeSplitProvider.get(CodeSplitProvider.java:48)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.ProxyImpl.getPresenter(ProxyImpl.java:46)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.ProxyPlaceAbstract.handleRequest(ProxyPlaceAbstract.java:193)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.ProxyPlaceAbstract.access$0(ProxyPlaceAbstract.java:192)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.ProxyPlaceAbstract$1.onPlaceRequest(ProxyPlaceAbstract.java:143)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceRequestInternalEvent.dispatch(PlaceRequestInternalEvent.java:134)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceRequestInternalEvent.dispatch(PlaceRequestInternalEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEventFromSource(SimpleEventBus.java:96)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEventFromSource(SimpleEventBus.java:62)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus.castFireEventFromSource(EventBus.java:75)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEventFromSource(SimpleEventBus.java:67)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceManagerImpl.fireEvent(PlaceManagerImpl.java:146)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceManagerImpl.doRevealPlace(PlaceManagerImpl.java:121)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceManagerImpl.revealPlace(PlaceManagerImpl.java:339)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.place.ClientPlaceManager.revealDefaultPlace(ClientPlaceManager.java:24)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceManagerImpl.onValueChange(PlaceManagerImpl.java:264)
    at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.dispatch(ValueChangeEvent.java:128)
    at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.dispatch(ValueChangeEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImpl.fireEvent(HistoryImpl.java:75)
    at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.fire(ValueChangeEvent.java:43)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImpl.fireHistoryChangedImpl(HistoryImpl.java:82)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.History.fireCurrentHistoryState(History.java:121)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceManagerImpl.revealCurrentPlace(PlaceManagerImpl.java:310)
    at com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.GameTestingYou.onModuleLoad(GameTestingYou.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

```
package com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.rs.gwtp.gametestingyou.client.gin.ClientGinjector;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.DelayedBindRegistry;



    public class GameTestingYou implements EntryPoint {

private final ClientGinjector ginjector = GWT.create(ClientGinjector.class);

@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
    // This is required for Gwt-Platform proxy's generator
    DelayedBindRegistry.bind(ginjector);

    ginjector.getPlaceManager().revealCurrentPlace();   

}

    }
```

Comment: Could you post the full exception?

Comment: Ok I've posted full exception? Can you please tell me what and why are you looking for?

Comment: I think problem is in constructor of PieChartView class: @Inject
 public PieChartView(final Binder binder) {
   widget = binder.createAndBindUi(this);
   PieChart pieChart = new PieChart(createTable(), createOptions());
  
 }

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor try to initialize `pieChart` before calling `createAndBindUi`

```java
@Inject
public @UiConstructor PieChartView(final Binder binder) {
    pieChart = new PieChart(createTable(), createOptions());
    widget = binder.createAndBindUi(this);
    chartPanel.add(pieChart);
}
```

Comment: I had that idea lest night, I've try that now again and onModuleLoad() threw me exception again. I've try to define PieChart as a parameter in that constructor and it has a same effect. I'm going to add one more peace of code to this issue. Entry point for this example.

Comment: How to load this api to Entry point class, I've tried this to no avail: VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, PieChart.PACKAGE);

Comment: By initializing `pieChart` do you get the same exception?

Comment: Yes I do. Did you manage to get this same result from my code or you have a working example?

Comment: Your previous exception was a `NullPointerException`. If you put a breakpoint in the `PieChartView` constructor, at what line does it throw the exception.

Comment: When I set up a Breakpoint on constructor method of PieChartView I get exception at this line pieChart = new PieChart(createTable(), createOptions()); When I step into this line it shows where it originated. Line 1036 className=null IN THIS METHOD  @Override
  protected synchronized Class<?> findClass(String className)
      throws ClassNotFoundException {
    if (className == null) {
      throw new ClassNotFoundException("null class name",
          new NullPointerException());
    }   in a class CompilingClassLoader.

Comment: I would debug your code until you find what is causing this NPE. It might be in `createOptions` or `createTable` but without the code it's hard to help.

Comment: I manage to add PieChart to RootPanel. Problem was that my class that implements EntryPoint class didn't load needed package. Then I loaded it with VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, PieChart.PACKAGE); and then add Runnable interface. Now when I made this object pieChart I just need to add it to panel that I want or PresenterWidget. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out that this issue is specific for GWT-P because EntryPoint class doesn't load needed PACKAGE. It need to be loaded with this method
    VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, PieChart.PACKAGE);
and add Runnable interface to class which implements EntryPoint class, like this sample:

```
Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            PieChart pieChart = new PieChart(createTable(), createOptions());
            Panel panel = RootPanel.get();
            panel.add(pieChart);

        }

        private AbstractDataTable createTable() {
                DataTable data = DataTable.create();
                data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Task");
                data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Hours per Day");
                data.addRows(2);
                data.setValue(0, 0, "Work");
                data.setValue(0, 1, 14);
                data.setValue(1, 0, "Sleep");
                data.setValue(1, 1, 10);
            return data;
        }

        private Options createOptions() {
                Options options = Options.create();
                options.setWidth(400);
                options.setHeight(240);
                options.setTitle("My Daily Activities");
                return options;

        }


    };
```

but this will add, in this example pieChart, to RootPanel, just now to figure out how to add this object pieChart to specific PresenterWidget. When I do this I will made a tutorial :)

Answer (score 0):

Success!!! This is how I FINALLY done what I intended: To add some chart to existing GWT-P project. When I was sure API set up was fine I figure out that this is solution:

UiBinder just need to have HTML table:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">

<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
ui:generateFormat='com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.format.PropertiesFormat'
ui:generateKeys='com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.keygen.MD5KeyGenerator'
ui:generateLocales='default'     xmlns:c="urn:import:com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart" 
xmlns:v="urn:import:com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations">

<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="chartPanel">
</g:HTMLPanel>
    </ui:UiBinder>
```

Then View should be simple as this:

```
    public class PieChartView extends ViewImpl implements PieChartPresenter.MyView {

private final Widget widget;
@UiField HTMLPanel chartPanel;

public interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, PieChartView> {
}

@Inject
public @UiConstructor PieChartView(final Binder binder) {   
    widget = binder.createAndBindUi(this);

}

@Override
public Widget asWidget() {
    return widget;
}
public HTMLPanel getChartPanel(){
    return chartPanel;
}
```

}

And Then PresenterWidget, need to load appropriate PACKAGE via VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, PieChart.PACKAGE); like this:

```
    public class PieChartPresenter extends
    PresenterWidget<PieChartPresenter.MyView> {

public interface MyView extends View {
    public HTMLPanel getChartPanel();
}

@Inject
public PieChartPresenter(final EventBus eventBus, final MyView view) {
    super(eventBus, view);
}

@Override
protected void onBind() {
    super.onBind();

    Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            PieChart pieChart = new PieChart(createTable(), createOptions());
            /*Panel panel = RootPanel.get();*/
            /*panel.add(pieChart);*/
            Panel panel = getView().getChartPanel();
            panel.add(pieChart);
        }

        private AbstractDataTable createTable() {
                DataTable data = DataTable.create();
                data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Task");
                data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Hours per Day");
                data.addRows(2);
                data.setValue(0, 0, "Work");
                data.setValue(0, 1, 14);
                data.setValue(1, 0, "Sleep");
                data.setValue(1, 1, 10);
            return data;
        }

        private Options createOptions() {
                Options options = Options.create();
                options.setWidth(400);
                options.setHeight(240);
                options.setTitle("My Daily Activities");
                return options;

        }

    };

    VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, PieChart.PACKAGE);

}
/*Ovde prmeniti method*/
@Override
protected void onReset() {
    super.onReset();

}
```

}

Now this is for testing purpose only, and it was a result which I intended: To place PieChart in PresenterWidget and present it on call.

Comment: I'm sure this could be done in different ways so I'm anxious to here them. Cheers! (Now to refactor :)